# ClassLoader Tracking on WebLogic Aplication Server Installed as the Service

Tags: java, weblogic

We are using WLS server instance running as windows service ([Setting Up a WebLogic Server Instance as a Windows Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21048/winservice.htm#START143)) and we facing some class collision, therefore we set up **-verbose:class** parameter to see CL resource details.

But after server restart it doesn't wrote the JRE process output to file specified in System property parameter:

> -Dweblogic.Stdout="d:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\myWLSdomain\
>   stdout.txt"

I searched for any verbose output as e.g.:

> [Loaded java.lang.Object from C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\rt.jar]

but I didn't find any. Therefore I checked windows registry key generated by **WL_HOME\server\bin\wlsvc** script, if contains all our specified parameters and also searched if is possible to specify verbose output by any next JRE parameter, but without result.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching in registry I found that **WLSVC** generated system service parameters keys at following location:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\{service_name}\Parameters]
>   .. 
>   "Log"= 
>   ..

one of parameters is **Log** sub-key, when I set it properly, JRE process started to use specified location for logging all details.